# Grouping by 90 Minute Intervals

Tags: t-sql

I'm trying to group records with a DATETIME field into 90 minute intervals.

I can group by any number of minutes which 60 is evenly divisible by using:

```
SET @Interval = 3 -- Every 3 Minutes
SELECT   CAST(
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [TIME_STAMP],112)            + ' ' +
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, [TIME_STAMP]))  + ':' +
     CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(mi, [TIME_STAMP]) / @Interval * @Interval)
             AS DATETIME) INTERVAL_TIME
```

or group by whole hours using:

```
SET @Interval = 4 --Every 4 hours 
SELECT CAST(
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), [TIME_STAMP],112) + ' ' +
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(2), DATEPART(hh, [TIME_STAMP]) / @Interval * @Interval ) 
            + ':00'
            AS DATETIME) INTERVAL_TIME
```

How do I group by 90 minutes or 1.5 hours ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `DATEDIFF(minute, 0, [TimeStamp])` to get the amount of minutes gone from epoch. Then you can simply divide by 90 and get the group you are in.

Maybe you have to add some offset. With `DATEADD(minute, [your group]*90, 0)` you get the starting time of that special group.

For your code (+ reduction of the many casts):

```
DECLARE @Interval int = 90
DECLARE @OffsetTime datetime = 0

SELECT DATEADD(minute, (DATEDIFF(minute, @OffsetTime, [TimeStamp]) / @Interval) * @Interval, @OffsetTime) INTERVAL_TIME
```

Notice that this code works for any interval you want to group by.

Answer (score 1):

Well there are 16 individual 90minute intervals in a day and each day is made up of 1440 minutes.

Calculate the current minute of the day and calculate its interval. Assume its 15:20

```
ROUND(1440 / ((DATEPART(hh, [TIME_STAMP]) * 60) + DATEPART(mm, [TIME_STAMP])), 0, 1)
```

This turns into:

```
ROUND(1440 / ((15*60) + 20), 0, 1)
```

So you're answer is 10. The 10th interval of the day. Add this calculation to your columns and group by it.

```
SELECT Col1, Col2, ROUND(1440 / ((DATEPART(hh, [TIME_STAMP]) * 60) + DATEPART(mm, [TIME_STAMP])), 0, 1)
    FROM MyTable
    GROUP BY    ROUND(1440 / ((DATEPART(hh, [TIME_STAMP]) * 60) + DATEPART(mm, [TIME_STAMP])), 0, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

assuming you have a table with `transaction_date` column which is of datetime, you could do something like this -

```
select count(1) from tbl_master group by datediff(minute,cast(floor(cast(transaction_date as float)) as datetime),transaction_date)/90
```

here we are casting the `transaction_date` to float and then flooring it. therefore the time part will be removed from the datetime. then we are taking the total minutes passed using `datediff` and dividing it by 90 for 1.5 hours.